# Get desktop width in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a web site built on WP with the slider on the main page. Each slide on the slider has path to background image stored on server. Say, for slide1 it is /images/slide1.jpg.

I want to substitute /images/slide1-wide.jpg for desktop width > 1400px.

CSS is not an option because path to image is evaluated dynamically from database.

I've added js that checks window width, but it acts AFTER the image is loaded. So the only thing I has been able to achieve was to draw original image and then redraw it. From user's point of view it looks awful (bad image -> blink -> correct image).

I've tried 51degrees plugin but it's able only to detect mobile devices.

How can I obtain the window width on the server side during main page drawing?

Comment: short answer is you can't

Comment: you may be able to use some conditional css or media queries to change the path to the image you want to use ie if its desktop /path/to images/desktop/imagename.jpg and if its mobile  /path/to images/mobile/imagename.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think you can select an image with this script before your image displayed.
So your users will not see 'bad image'.

```
<script>
$(function(){
width = $(window).width();
alert(width);
if (width > 1400) {
 $('#divimg').html("<img src='/images/slide1-wide.jpg'>");
}
else {
 $('#divimg').html("<img src='/images/slide1.jpg'>");
}
})
</script>
<div id="divimg"></div>
```